# How to make resize handle visible in After Effects final rendering?

Tags: animation, adobe-after-effects

I'm am making an interaction design of a wireframe wherein I want to show the geometric lines such as the resize handle.

The pen tool path with handles etc.

Is there a plugin that allows me to show these elements while animating.

Answer (score 0):

For a professional approach, you might want to actually create these elements as artwork and animate that. Otherwise perhaps you could screen record you interacting with these elements and incorporate that screen recording into your animation.